# geopandas looping with lambda function

Tags: pandas, geojson, geopandas, shapely

I have a geojson document 'streets' with a column "geometry" filled with data of type shapely Point.
I have another geojson document 'quartiers' with a column 'geometry" with data of type shapely Polygon and in same document I have another column called "l_qu".
What I am trying to achieve is looping through all streets['geometry] with a lambda in quartiers['geometry'] and assign the corresponding 'l_qu' match value in a new column 'matchquartier' in 'streets'.
There are 150K lines in streets (the adresses)  and 80  lines in quartiers (the neighboorhoods)
The lambda for I built is :

```
def checkquartier(point):
    return quartiers[quartiers["geometry"].apply(point.within)]["l_qu"]
```

When running some test fo the lambda, say:
checkquartier(streets['geometry'][19]) , no issue, it returns:

19    La Chapelle
Name: l_qu, dtype: object

which is the expected result. The problem is when I try to do it for my whole doc with

```
streets["matchquartier"]=streets['geometry'].apply(lambda x: checkquartier(x))
```

It returns the error:
ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 80, placement implies 1

I know this is a broader pandas issue but the other fixes/answers I found on SO do not work in this case so wondering if there is something from the GeoPandas side that I am doing wrong ? Thanks

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas
import os
import shapely
from shapely.geometry import Polygon, LineString, Point,box
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from shapely import wkt

quartiers = geopandas.read_file("https://parisdata.opendatasoft.com/explore/dataset/quartier_paris/download/?format=geojson&timezone=Europe/Berlin&lang=fr")
streets=geopandas.read_file("https://opendata.paris.fr/explore/dataset/adresse_paris/download/?format=geojson&timezone=Europe/Berlin&lang=fr")

def checkquartier(point):
    return quartiers[quartiers["geometry"].apply(point.within)]["l_qu"]   

streets["matchquartier"]=streets['geometry'].apply(lambda x: checkquartier(x))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can just use a spatial join. This is working for me.

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
import shapely
from shapely import wkt
from shapely.geometry import Polygon, LineString, Point, box, shape
import json

quartiers = gpd.read_file("quartier_paris.csv")
streets=gpd.read_file("adresse_paris.csv")

quartiers["geometry"] = quartiers["geom"].apply(lambda x: shape(json.loads(x)))

streets["geometry"] = streets["geom"].apply(lambda x: shape(json.loads(x)))

sj = gpd.sjoin(streets, quartiers)
streets.join(sj["l_qu"])
```

Comment: Thansk for your answer, unfortunately this is not working for me, which library does the "shape" function comes from? 
In the meantime I found a dirty way to do it, probably dangerous but it does the trick 
```
for i in range(len(streets)) :
    try:
        streets.loc[i, "quartier"]=checkquartier(streets.loc[i, "geometry"]).values[0]
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: I updated the imports in my answer. The shape function comes from shapely.